# many to many relationship between different types using a through table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been trying to understand how to get a many to many relationship working correctly.  Here's the simplified model of Entity and Event.  The relationships I'm trying to model are:

- Entities have a many to many with other Entities
- Entities have a many to many with Events

From a lookup perspective, here's what works so far:

- look up entities that I have a one to many relationship with
- look up entities that have a relationship to this entity (reverse/backwards relation)
- look up events that I have a one to many relationship with

But I haven't been able to figure out:

- look up entities that have a relationship to this event (reverse/backward relation)

  ```
  class Entity2EntityRel(Model):
      from_entity = ForeignKey('Entity', to_field='uuid',
                               related_name="from_entity")
      to_entity = ForeignKey('Entity', to_field='uuid',
                             related_name="to_entity")
      relation = CharField(max_length=64)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return json.dumps({
              "from_entity": str(self.from_entity),
              "relation": str(self.relation),
              "to_entity": str(self.to_event)
          })


  class Entity2EventRel(Model):
      from_entity = ForeignKey('Entity', to_field='uuid',
                               related_name="from_entity_ev")
      to_event = ForeignKey('Event', to_field='uuid',
                            related_name="to_event_en")
      relation = CharField(max_length=64)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return json.dumps({
              "from_entity": str(self.from_entity),
              "relation": str(self.relation),
              "to_event": str(self.to_event)
          })




  class Entity(PolymorphicModel):
      uuid = UUIDField(unique=True)
      name = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
      entity_rels = ManyToManyField(
          'Entity',
          through='Entity2EntityRel',
          related_name="related_entity_set",
          symmetrical=False)
      event_rels = ManyToManyField(
          'Event',
          through='Entity2EventRel',
          related_name="related_event_set",
          symmetrical=False)

      def add_entity_rel(self, entity, relation_name):
          relationship, created = Entity2EntityRel.objects.get_or_create(
              from_entity=self,
              to_entity=entity,
              relation=relation_name)
          return relationship

      # return entities related to me
      def get_entity_rels(self, relation_name):
          return self.entity_rels.filter(
              to_entity__relation=relation_name,
              to_entity__from_entity=self)

      # return items that have a relation to me
      def get_related_entities(self, relation_name):
          return self.related_entity_set.filter(
              from_entity__relation=relation_name,
              from_entity__to_entity=self)

      def add_event_rel(self, event, relation_name):
          relationship, created = Entity2EventRel.objects.get_or_create(
              from_entity=self,
              to_event=event,
              relation=relation_name)
          return relationship

      # return events related to me
      def get_event_rels(self, relation_name):
          return self.event_rels.filter(
              to_event_en__relation=relation_name,
              to_event_en__from_entity=self)
  ```

#### Now how do I get the entities that are related to a particular event?